# failed to connect to cloud storage after deploying to gcp app engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm developing a Flask app on App Engine VM. I want to upload file to Google Cloud Storage so i use `storage_client = storage.Client()` to connect to cloud storage. My app is working perfectly without error when testing in VM alone. However, after I deployed using `gcloud app deploy` and tested the upload function on my deployed app, it failed and returned `Internet 500` error. The log showed the traceback and it is due to the line of code connecting to cloud storage: `storage_client = storage.Client()`

The specific error is `__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given` shown in cloud storage library function. I have python 3.5 for this app and i really don't know how to resolve this. Any help would be really appreciated!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py\", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File \"/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py\", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File \"/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py\", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File \"/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py\", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File \"/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py\", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File \"/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py\", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File \"/home/vmagent/app/main.py\", line 59, in select_date
    generate_report(log_lists)
  File \"/home/vmagent/app/main.py\", line 83, in generate_report
    storage_client = storage.Client()
  File \"/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py\", line 86, in __init__
    self._connection = Connection(self, client_info=client_info)
  File \"/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/_http.py\", line 33, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(client, client_info)
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

And below is my "requirements.txt":

```
Flask==1.0.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
firebase-admin==2.13.0
google-cloud-firestore==0.29.0
google-cloud-storage==1.17.0
lxml==3.7.3
```

Comment: Can you share your `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: Flask==1.0.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
firebase-admin==2.13.0
google-cloud-firestore==0.29.0
google-cloud-storage==1.17.0
lxml==3.7.3

Comment: Is this the problem with google-cloud-storage version? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using old libraries. Update your requirements.txt to use the current versions.

For example:

You are using `google-cloud-firestore==0.29.0` but the current version is `google-cloud-firestore==1.3.0`

Most of your modules are out of date and in some case not compatible (and ancient library with a current library).

Comment: I've got the same error on the last AI Platform Prediction runtime 1.15 (google-cloud-storage 1.19.1).

Comment: @PilipenokOleg - Create a new question with your details.